# Data access across multiple migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am building an application using entity framework and I have used the Identity module to create the user tables. Other data I have created separately so I now have two migrations in the project. The two contexts actually store data into the same database. I am now at the point where I want to link data to the user that created it. Do I:

Query across the two contexts (if so how is this done)

Or should I migrate the identity tables into my schema so that I only have one. This seems a shame as I like the idea of updating parts of the db separately.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think querying across two different DataContexts is supported.  There's nothing wrong with having an entity present in two different DataContexts.  Say if you want to have a User present in both contexts so that you can associate other entities to a user (who created, modified it, whatever) there's nothing wrong with that.  As you said it's all the same database.

The only other way would be bringing down the data from each data context and doing operations in memory with Linq to objects.  But that would be far less efficient.

Comment: Your right you can't. I removed answer. base {System.Exception} = {"The query contains references to items defined on a different data context."} .

Comment: I will bring the tables required into my context and I believe that I can still keep the Identity context also.

Comment: That should work just fine for you, onesixtyfourth.  I often do it that way.